# Firebase GET request blocked by simple firebase rules

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following collection group query:

```
const userInRooms = await firestore()
        .collectionGroup('userRooms')
        .where('uid', '==', authenticatedUser.uid)
        .get();
```

And it works fine.
But since I added security rule:

```
match /rooms/{docId} {
      allow read;
      allow write;
      match /userRooms/{docId} {
        allow read;
        allow write;
      }
    }
```

`userRooms` is subcollection in `rooms`.
It stopped working and I getting:

> NativeFirebaseError: [firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cascading the sub-collections rules that way doesn't work for [collection group queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query). A recursive wildcard must be present at the beginning of the path so it'll match any collections with that name. Try:

```
match /rooms/{docId} {
  //...
}

match /{path=**}/userRooms/{docId} {
  allow read, write: if true;
}
```

Do change the rules as required instead of allowing everyone to read the database (unless they are allowed to).

Comment: It worked but I saw in documentation that I can do `match /city/{id} { match /landmark/{id} }` what is different here?

Comment: @1110 are they using collection group queries in that docs? Checkout this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#collection_group_queries_and_security_rules) for security rules for collectionGRoup queries.